# Upgrade Server 2019 Standard

Tags: windows-server

Every time I turn around I am seeing a reference to Upgrade Server 2019. It almost looks like it is supposed to follow Windows 10 in doing "Feature Updates". When you do a winver on a 2019 Server is does indeed come back and say build 1809 just like Windows 10 but I can't find these "Feature Updates" for Server 2019. Has anyone seen such a thing and can you tell me how to to it?

Comment: Run Windows Update.

Comment: Feature updates don’t exist  on Windows Server 2019.  If *winver* indicate 1809 then you would have to wait until the next version is released which would be in 2022.  Windows Server cannot be upgraded to Windows Server they are licensed differently

Comment: The eventual upgrade to Windows Server 2022 (based on 21H2) would not be free unless you have paid for that privilege through Microsoft.  Furthermore, any edition of Windows Server is only legitimately licensed through a volume license anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server comes in [two channels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/servicing-channels-19): Semi-Annual and Long-Term.

- The Semi-Annual channel gets new releases twice a year. The OS is simply called "Windows Server", currently on version 2004, and receives feature upgrades through Windows Update.
- The Long-Term channel is static. If you have Server 2016 then you have Server 2016, and if you have Server 2019 then you have Server 2019. New versions only come out every few years, and although [in-place upgrading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/upgrade/upgrade-overview) is supported, it has to be done manually.

So if you have "Windows Server 2019" based on build 1809, then you're on the Long-Term channel and you will *always* continue to have Server 2019 build 1809. The only way to upgrade is by running the new installer from an ISO image, after the next version comes out.

Comment: Thanks! That brings up a couple additional questions. The first being is the Semi-Annual what use to be R2? the second being can you give me a link on where to purchase the Semi-Annual?

Comment: You already have a Semi-Annual license. Your other question is unclear.

Comment: No. If you look close I have a long term. I did find the semi-annual. It follows the Windows 10 Features Updates. Two per year. It just isn't free. Your need to purchase Software Assurance annually.